# How to specify a username using connection string in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

My ASP.Net Core app keeps trying to login into database using a "default" username even though I specify a different user in a connection string, which I am using. That is I keep getting the same exception that says:

*An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SqlException: Cannot open database "testDB" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-555DDD\skorejen'*.

Even though I am using a connection string that has a different username defined.

How can I fix it so that my app logins with the connection-string specified username?

Connection String:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=testDB;User Id=myusername;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
```

ASP.Net Core Startup.cs file:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
             services.AddDbContext<OrderContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        }
```

Comment: When using a Tructed Connection, the credentials of the authenticated *Windows user* is used; the username and password options will be ignored. You either need to have the application run under the appropriate AD account (via impersonation), add the users that would be using the application to the valid logins (which would likely be easier by using AD groups, rather than adding each of their logins) or use SQL Authetication instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to enable `sql authentication mode`, add the user to the sql server logins and specify the password in the connection string.

Example connection string:

> Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
>   Password=myPassword;

([source](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/))

Eanabling `sql authentication mode`:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Your `ConnectionStrings` has to be in below formats:

**With credentials (SQL authentication):**

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "Server=myServerAddress; Database=myDataBase; User Id=myUsername; Password=myPassword; Trusted_Connection=false; MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
}
```

**Without credentials (Windows authentication):**

```
"ConnectionStrings": {       
  "DefaultConnection": "Server=myServerAddress; Database=myDataBase; Trusted_Connection=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true"        
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm using a XAML `app.config` so had to adapt from this `json` - which was quite trivial. '<connectionStrings>
<add name="AppNameForDb" connectionString="Server= ... MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>'